# Проблема System.IO.EndOfStreamException

Tags: c#

Всем привет, столкнулся с такой проблемой! Пишу софту для редактирования файла и у меня ругается на стринг. Вот сама ошибка: `System.IO.EndOfStreamException не обработано
  HResult=-2147024858`

```
class StringBinaryReader : BinaryReader
{
    public StringBinaryReader(Stream input) : base(input)
    {

    }

    public override string ReadString()
    {
        Byte[] String = new Byte[base.ReadUInt16()];
        for (int i = 0; i < String.Length; i++)
        {
            String[i] = base.ReadByte();
        }
        return System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(String);
    }
}
```

Comment: Уберите скрин и положите код.

Comment: `base.Position=0;` в начале `ReadString()` и вот это жёстко `Byte[] String = ...`

Comment: А в чем проблема то? Ну кончился у вас поток, вы же не проверяете, всё вы из файла прочитали или не все, вы просто читаете сколько вам захотелось, потому и нарываетесь на конец потока. А при попытке чтения из потока, когда он кончился, вам и выскакивает это исключение.

Comment: а блин точно...base.ReadUInt16() вернет не размер стрима, а прочтет 2 байта из него и превратит в UInt16. а далее может быть и нету ничего. а вы читаете...

Comment: Всем спасибо за помощь! Я сам накосячил и забыл посмотреть на сам HEX код в файле. Причина была в том что нужно было не UInt16 использовать, а Byte